# Rally API query OR clause

Tags: rally

I am using rally-node module to retrieve some data from Rally. My query clause looks like the following.

```
var query = queryUtils.where('ClosedDate', '>=', '2016-12-22');
query = query.or('State', '!=', 'Closed');
```

I would like these query parameters to be bundled together so that the query reads:

```
(ClosedDate >= '2016-12-22' OR State != 'Closed') and (THE REST)
```

This is not happening for me and I was wondering what I am going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSAPI query syntax is a little bit verbose with its groupings and many, many parentheses.  Your code above should produce this, which is correct:

```
((ClosedDate >= '2016-12-22') OR (State != 'Closed'))
```

Then if you and something on, you'll get this:

```
query = query.and('Environment', '=', 'Test');

(((ClosedDate >= '2016-12-22') OR (State != 'Closed')) AND (Environment = 'Test'))
```

Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks Kyle! That is indeed what I am seeing. So the issue must be in how I am implementing this part of that module. The requirements I have lists different types of queries users use in the actual Rally portal and this is what they have listed. Dizzying number of brackets indeed (((((((((((((ClosedDate >= 2016-12-22)) OR (State != Closed)) AND ...
Notice the extra paren after 2016-12-22